# Формирование списка из элементов столбца таблицы Excel, которые соотносятся с элементами другого столбца

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlrd

Я записываю элементы столбцов таблицы Excel в списки. Хочу при нахождении определенных значений в одном столбце, записывать значения другого столбца, соответствующие им по номеру строки.
Запись сделана так:

```
  import xlrd

    excel_data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('./testbook.xlsx')
    sheet = excel_data_file.sheet_by_index(0)

    ku_ind_lst = sheet.col_values(0)
    sys_name_lst = sheet.col_values(2)
```

При анализе этих списков мне необходимо проверять 3 столбец на наличие элементов xxx, yyy, zzz и формировать список из элементов 1 столбца, которые соответствуют найденным xxx, yyy, zzz. Можно ли так делать?

```
for i in range(0, len(sys_name_lst)):
    if sys_name_lst[i] == 'xxx' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'yyy' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'zzz':
        b = sys_name_lst[i]
        c = ku_ind_lst[i]
        print(b)
        print(c)
```

Comment: Какое-то странное условие: `if sys_name_lst[i] == 'xxx' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'yyy' and sys_name_lst[i] == 'zzz'`. Мне кажется, должно быть `or`.

Comment: А по поводу Вашего вопроса, думаю Вам поможет метод [row_values](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.row_values)